# Add Wysiwyg attribute to category in Magento 2.2.4

Tags: category-attribute, wysiwyg, magento2.2.4

I followed this reference [Inchoo](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/add-category-attribute-magento-2/) to add new Wysiwyg attribute to category in Magento 2.2.4. It's working fine. My custom attribute successfully added in the category but it's showing only textarea instead of Wysiwyg editor.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After digging into magento attribute table structure I found that Magento has changed `wysiwyg_enabled` field to `is_wysiwyg_enabled` from `catalog_eav_attribute` table.

So we need to change `wysiwyg_enabled` to `is_wysiwyg_enabled` from setup script

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
    'menu_content',
    [
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Menu Content',
        'input' => 'textarea',
        'required' => false,
        'sort_order' => 4,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
        'group' => 'General Information',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Is this working for you ? i got only textarea instead of wysiwyg

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari Please check your admin configuration Stores->Configuration->General->Content Management->WYSIWYG Options->Enable WYSIWYG Editor Set to "Disabled By Default" or "Enabled By Default". If it is set to "Disabled Completely" you will get only Textarea.

Comment: Event WYSIWYG enable in admin but not showing editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'menu_content',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Menu Content',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'is_wysiwyg_enabled'      => TRUE,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

define in XML file `app\code\SilkSoftware\ModuleName\view\adminhtml\ui_component\category_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">

        <field name="menu_item">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">menu_item</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Menu Item</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string"></item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category :: ENTITY, 'menu_content', [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'Menu Content',
                        'input' => 'textarea',
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 110,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                        "default" => "",
                        "class"    => "",
                        "note"       => ""
            ]
            );
```